# Play framework, Setting HTTP POST request headers

Tags: java, web-services, oauth, playframework, google-api

## Question

When using the Google Plus Sign In Api with the Play Framework do you have to set headers in a different way? Is there something I am doing wrong here?

## Background

I am using [Play Framework](https://www.playframework.com/)(in Java) to use the [Google Plus Sign in Api](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer).
I am running into issues on the second leg of OAuth authentication, exchanging the `Authorization Code` for a `Token`.

## Basic OAuth Flow

[Pretty Picture](https://developers.google.com/accounts/images/webflow.png)

1. Redirect user to `User login/Consent screen`

   - This asks the user if they want to grant you application permission to the requested scopes
   - URL: `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth`
2. Exchange `Authorization Code` for a `Token`

   - If the user gives your application permission then they will be redirected to a URL you specify, in that URL(As a `GET` param) will be an `Authorization Code`.
   - Your application can then use this `Authoriztion Code` to get a `Token` from the server
   - Your application does this by making a HTTP request to a endpoint on the Google Servers(Or whatever service you are using)

     - URL: `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token`
3. Use `Token` in API requests

## The Issue

To Exchange the `Authorization Code` for a `Token`, with the Google Plus Sign In Api, you must make a `POST` request to `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token` with the following perimeters

```
{
  "code": "Security Code Returned from Step 1",
  "client_id": "Client Id that was given to you in GApi Console",
  "client_secret": "Client Secret that was given to you in the GApi Console",
  "redirect_uri": "Redirect Uri you specified in the GApi Console",
  "grant_type": "authorization_code"
}
```

However when I make this request with all the correct parameters I get this error

```
{
  "error" : "invalid_request",
  "error_description" : "Required parameter is missing: grant_type"
}
```

From the Google Plus Sign in Api

To make HTTP requests in The Play Framework you use the `WS Library`. I make the request like this

```
public static F.Promise<Result> OAuthCallback(String state, String code){
  /*
    Note:
      - The GoogleStrategy class is just a class that holds all my GApi credentials
      - The parameters (String state, String code) are just GET params from Step 1, returned by the GApi
  */

  //Make URL builder
  WSRequestHolder requestHolder = WS.url(GoogleStrategy.getTokenUrl);

  //Set headers
  requestHolder.setHeader("code", code);
  requestHolder.setHeader("client_id", GoogleStrategy.clientId);
  requestHolder.setHeader("client_secret", GoogleStrategy.clientSecret);
  requestHolder.setHeader("redirect_uri", GoogleStrategy.redirectUri);
  requestHolder.setHeader("grant_type", GoogleStrategy.grantType);//GoogleStrategy.grantType = "authorization_code"

  //Make HTTP request and tell program what to do once the HTTP request is finished
  F.Promise<Result> getTokenPromise = requestHolder.post("").map(
    new F.Function<WSResponse, Result>() {
      public Result apply(WSResponse response){
        return ok(response.asJson());//Returning result for debugging
      }
    }
  );

  return getTokenPromise;//Return promise, Play Framework will handle the Asynchronous stuff
}
```

As you can see, I set the header `grant_type`. Just to make sure setting headers was working I made a program that spits out the headers of a request in NodeJS([Source](https://gist.github.com/Noah-Huppert/a18a659f3069a6aece57)) and this was the result

```
{
  "HEADERS": {
    "host": "127.0.0.1:3000",
    "code": "4/qazYoReIJZAYO9izlTjjJA.gihwUJ6zgoERgtL038sCVnsvSfAJkgI",
    "grant_type": "authorization_code",
    "client_secret": "XXXX-CENSORED FOR SECURITY PURPOSES-XXX",
    "redirect_uri": "http://127.0.0.1:9000/api/users/auth/google/callback",
    "client_id": "XXXX-CENSORED FOR SECURITY PURPOSES-XXX",
    "content-type": "text/plain; charset=utf-8",
    "connection": "keep-alive",
    "accept": "*/*",
    "user-agent": "NING/1.0",
    "content-length": "14"
  }
}
```

Comment: You should update your answer with the error you get.

Comment: You already posted that information (your code) in the comment in my answer. I am asking for the error you get (ie the HTTP code and body you get from Google).

Comment: @Salem Oops Edited(That was stupid of me :P)

Comment: see my edit. Also you may try to use [url encoding](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) in you redirect_uri value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think those are not to be sent as headers but as a body. In the link you provided there is an example:

```
POST /o/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
Host: accounts.google.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

code=4/P7q7W91a-oMsCeLvIaQm6bTrgtp7&
client_id=8819981768.apps.googleusercontent.com&
client_secret={client_secret}&
redirect_uri=https://oauth2-login-demo.appspot.com/code&
grant_type=authorization_code
```

So pass them to your `post` call:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("code=").append(code)
    .append("&client_id=").append(GoogleStrategy.clientId)
    .append("&client_secret=").append( GoogleStrategy.clientSecret)
    .append("&redirect_uri=").append(GoogleStrategy.redirectUri)
    .append("&grant_type=").append(GoogleStrategy.grantType)

requestHolder.setContentType("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    .post(sb.toString());
```

Comment: Using [this code](http://pastebin.com/xhp09z8P)(Implementing what you suggested) I still get the same error from the Google Plus Login Api.